# creating dynamic array of string c++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I am struct to a very basic question. I want to create dynamically an array of string in c++.

How can I do that ?

**This is my attempt:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(){
    unsigned int wordsCollection = 6;
    unsigned int length = 6;

    std::string *collection = new std::string[wordsCollection];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < wordsCollection; ++i){
        std::cin>>wordsCollection[i];
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

But it giving the following error

```
error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
```

What's the error ?

And also if I'am getting input number from user, from `std::cin` can I create an array of that size statically ?

Comment: In the future please select your code block and use the `{}` button; this will make your code show up properly in the question.

Comment: You typed `wordsCollection[i]` instead of `collection[i]`. You can't use a size obtained *dynamically* (e.g. through `std::cin`) to create a static array. Also, the array is leaking since you never release it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You meant to type:

```
std::cin>>collection[i];
```

And you also need to `delete[]` `collection` (or you'll leak this memory).

It would be better use `std::vector<std::string> collection;` and avoid the raw pointer usage altogether:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const unsigned int wordsCollection = 6;

    std::vector<std::string> collection;
    std::string word;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < wordsCollection; ++i)
    {
        std::cin >> word;
        collection.push_back(word);
    }

    std::copy(collection.begin(),
              collection.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 10):

use `std::vector<string>`  or `std::list<string>` over hand rolling it.

Comment: But the real problem is that `wordsCollection` should be `collection`.

Comment: Oh my God how silly i am... Any how thanks... can you tell me the answer for my second question that can i create a static array of that

Comment: I agree, but if you choose to go ahead with `new std::string` do not forget to `delete[] collection` when you are done. It is a good idea to ensure that for every `new` you have a `delete`

Comment: You can't create an array of any size where you get the size at runtime. You can create a pointer to a buffer of n elements that acts like an array but you will have to delete it.  Thats one of the many reason using the stl containers are preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I think that should be:

```
std::cin >> collection[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a simple typo. `std::cin>>wordsCollection[i]` should be `std::cin>>collection[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you're trying access the elements of an int (i.e. `wordsCollection`), not an array of int (i.e. `collection`). What you should be writing is

```
std::cin>>collection[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> myStrings;
    myStrings.push_back(std::string("string1"));
    myStrings.push_back(std::string("string2"));

    std::vector<std::string>::iterator iter = myStrings.begin();
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator end = myStrings.end();
    while(iter != end)
    {
        std::cout << (*iter) << std::endl;
        ++iter;
    }
    return 0;
}
```